# A step in regards to the generalised weight space decomposition for lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

I am currently following the MIT lie algebra notes (for fun, not for h.w.!)  and I am stuck on a step in one of the main theorems of the lecture. The notes are found here, https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.745/classnotes.html , and the question is with regards to theorem 6.6 of lecture 6. The theorem is as follows:

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a finite-dimensional Lie algebra and π its representation on a finitedimensional vector space V , over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic 0. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a
nilpotent subalgebra of $\mathfrak{g}$. Then the following equalities hold.

$$V = \bigoplus_{\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}*}V^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\lambda} \ \ \ (2)$$

$$ \pi(\mathfrak{g}^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\alpha}) \ V^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\lambda} \subset V^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\lambda+ \alpha}  \ \ \ (3)$$

where $V^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\lambda}$ and $\mathfrak{g}^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\alpha}$ are the generalised weight spaces w.r.t to the rep $\pi$ and the adjoint rep.

The proof of this theorem is given below:

[image]

I am stuck on the establishment of (2), I don't get what induction is being done on. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4196804/decomposition-of-complex-lie-algebra-through-generalised-eigenspaces) for a proof, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I believe that this link takes me to a proof that given any $a\in \mathfrak{g}$ we can decompose the vector space into a direct sum of generalized eigenspaces w.r.t a single operator $\pi(a) \in End(V)$, my question is about using this result and extending it to the case of a decomposition of  **generalized weight spaces** w.r.t  a niltpotent subalgebra.

Comment: The post there proves $\mathfrak{g}=\oplus_{\lambda\in\Sigma(x)}\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}(x)$ for the generalized eigenspaces $\mathfrak{g}_{\lambda}(x)$, and the same works for your more general version $(2)$, i.e., for $V = \oplus_{\lambda \in \mathfrak{h}*}V^{\mathfrak{h}}_{\lambda}$.